# using std::accumulate when there is pointer

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, smart-pointers, accumulate

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22713351/13519156) the only solution when there is a pointer that points to a vector and we would like to use accumulate to sum up numbers?
Is there any simpler solution rather than writing a lambda function and using a four argument type of accumulating?

Also, for using `std::sort`, will the situation be the same?

Here is the code:

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    const int N=3; 

    auto  p=make_unique<array<int,N>> ();
    
    (*p)[0]=3;
    (*p)[1]=4;
    (*p)[2]=5;
    
    sum=accumulate(p,?,0); 
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your scenario is different than the linked question if it is as you described. The linked question discusses accumulation a vector of *pointers*; you seem to be asking how to accumulate from **a** pointer to **a** vector (of. something). Actual *real* code showing what you have, and what you're trying to do, is warranted if you want a *real* answer.

Comment: If you have a `vector<obj*>`, you have no choice but to use a lambda. If you want to accumulate a `vector<obj>*`, then you can use `std::accumulate(ptr->begin(), ptr->end(),0)`. Please clarify your use case with a code snippet.

Comment: @MAero2020 So it's like M.A said `std::accumulate(p->begin(), p->end(),0)` and the same idea will work for `std::sort`.

Comment: @M.A sorry, I added the code snippet

Comment: You do realize there's no vector in the code you posted...

Comment: @Blastfurnace Also  `const N=3;` is illegal. Probably a case of not the real code.

Comment: [Here's your code](https://godbolt.org/z/86aj1a) with syntax errors corrected and the correct include headers. Are you learning C++ from online tutorials or "competitive programming" sites? You might want a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks for the book! I am learning C++ through online tutorials

Comment: Unfortunately there's a **lot** of questionable content out there. Not everyone is suited to learning from books but I think the structure of a book is good for the language fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question:

```
std::accumulate(p->begin(), p->end(), 0);
```

The same syntax will work for other STL algorithms as well.

---

Other improvements to your code snippet:

Avoid using `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). Similarly for [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), it's considered bad practise.

<strike>`const N=3` -> `const auto N=3`</strike>

`std::array` is not a vector and you can initialise it directly using initializer-list syntax:

```
const auto* obj = new std::array<int,3>{3,4,5};
```